# Find the value of $3\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}+2\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{5}+\sin^{-1}\frac{142}{65\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the value of $3\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)+\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{142}{65\sqrt{5}}\right)$

My reference gives the solution $0$ to this problem.

**My Attempt**

$$
|x_1|=\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\implies
3\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{8}}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=\tan^{-1}\frac{11}{2}\\
|x_2|=\frac{1}{5}<1\implies2\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{5}=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{1-\frac{1}{25}}=\tan^{-1}\frac{10}{24}=\tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}\\
XY=\frac{11}{2}\frac{5}{12}=\frac{55}{24}>1\quad\&\quad X,Y>0\\
3\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{2}+2\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{5}=\tan^{-1}\frac{11}{2}+\tan^{-1}\frac{5}{12}=\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{11}{2}+\frac{5}{12}}{1-\frac{11}{2}\frac{5}{12}}\\
=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{142}{31}
$$
So I seem to get $\pi$ as the answer, what is going wrong here ?

Comment: That definitely looks positive to me!

Comment: Your reference is wrong.You should compute the value numerically. This cannot prove your answer is right but it can show your reference is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference is clearly wrong without calculating anything. Functions like $\tan^{-1}$ and $\sin^{-1}$ generate positive values for positive arguments, by convention. All your arguments are positive so the result must be positive too. Numeric check proves that your result is correct.